# How to change the color of following 3 tabs in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How to change the color of following 3 tabs in Android? In this I have used ViewPager (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) for tabs(not tab layout).
 I want to make these 3 tabs in orange color.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you show the Theme applied ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
....
app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
...
/>
```

selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me just add this in xml...

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
....
android:background=""

...
/>
```

Hope this will help you...